# Why foreach statements accept objects that implement the 'Collection' pattern instead of accept only objects that implement IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

Many people ask me why, and I don`t have a good answer for them.

Obviously there is a good reason. Does anyone know it?

I searched here and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127233/does-class-need-to-implement-ienumerable-to-use-foreach). It explains how it works, but not why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose you wanted the equivalent of an `IEnumerable<int>` but were using C# 1.0. You *could* implement `IEnumerable` - but that would require boxing and unboxing on each iteration. Using the sort of duck-typing version of `foreach` you could get away without any boxing. In many cases the boxing wouldn't actually be that harmful (I tend to find that [the performance hit is exaggerated](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/why-boxing-doesn-t-keep-me-awake-at-nights.aspx)) but it's still inelegant.

I strongly, *strongly* suspect that if generics had been around in C# 1.0, `foreach` would have been restricted to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Generics were the BIG MISSING FEATURE ("BMF") of v1.0, a fact which rippled throughout the framework and languages.  This is just one example of something that would have been designed differently, and now can't be fixed.

Comment: @Jay: Agreed. There will always be such things, of course - but I would personally rather they'd delayed by .NET 1.0 a year (or more) and put generics in. Big marketing headache. Fortunately of course this *particular* little complexity in C# doesn't actually cause much damage. There are worse :(

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple more advantages to duck-typed foreach versus IEnumerable:

1. There are some things which satisfy enough of the "IEnumerable" contract to be usable with "foreach", but which don't fully satisfy the contract, especially the ability to repeatedly get independent enumerators.  With regard this point, alloing "foreach" to accept either IEnumerator [generic or not] or IEnumerable [likewise] would be an alternative solution.

   Although some implementations of IEnumerable.GetEnumerator return a struct that implements IEnumerator, and although this is useful when using duck typing, the behavior can be problematic in some contexts.  The fact that foreach uses duck typing allows compilers to have a public GetEnumerator() function return a struct-type enumerator (which does not implement any interface) and have compilers use that, while having IEnumerable.GetEnumerator return a class.

The second advantage can really only be achieved via duck-typing.