# Can't implement IEnumerable<dynamic>, probably doing something I shouldn't

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm writing a small game for learning purposes and I'm having trouble making a class iterable with foreach. It's a class that many of the game objects will implement, giving them a string indexed data store of the `<dynamic>` type. I have array style access working so I can go `object["arbitrary-key"] = foo;` but I'd like to be able to `foreach(dynamic value in object)`. So it looks like I need to implement IEnumerable, but it looks like there's a restriction on the `<dynamic>` type for this interface.

`Error  CS1966  'GameObject': cannot implement a dynamic interface 'IEnumerable<dynamic>'`

Here's the class:

```
public class GameObject : IEnumerable<dynamic>
{
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> data = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

    public GameObject()
    {

    }

    //Overloads the [] operator to allow array style access
    public dynamic this[string key]
    {
        get { return this.data[key]; }
        set { data[key] = value; }
    }

    //Overloads foreach iteration
    public IEnumerator<dynamic> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (dynamic d in data)
        {
            yield return d;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator<dynamic> IEnumerable<dynamic>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

So I'm thinking I might be barking up the wrong tree and need to reassess this class. Maybe there's something I can just have game objects implement that has this behavior built in? Or another way of accomplishing my goal?

Comment: Fun fact, [you don't actually need to implement IEnumerable for your class to work with foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127233/does-class-need-to-implement-ienumerable-to-use-foreach)

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[Scott Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain) pointed me in the right direction. The code looks much better now too. Here's the new class.

```
public class GameObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> data = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

    public GameObject()
    {

    }

    //Overloads the [] operator to allow array style access
    public dynamic this[string key]
    {
        get { return this.data[key]; }
        set { data[key] = value; }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, dynamic>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return data.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

All I had to do was implement a `GetEnumerator()` function that passed the enumerator of my `Dictionary` along.